# Retrieving an Azure AD refresh-token from Android app

Tags: android, azure, api, azure-active-directory

**I have an android application that can upload files to Sharepoint. It authenticates with AzureAD. It works fine if I manually create a refresh-token, but I can't figure out how to do this in code in Android.**

FYI, we also have an external web application (MVC) in which we can generate refresh tokens. It does this by following the authorization flow here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow
The application follows the authorization flow by generating an authorization code, using that code to generate an access/refresh token and then retrieving the refresh token.

This proces is already complex in our web application, but we now want to implement such thing in our Android application.

**My question is, how can we implement this authorization flow in an android app?** When the user requests an authorization code he is automatically redirected to an azure login page. Is this also possible with an http client library in Android? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried [MSAL for Android](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android)?

Comment: In your Android app, redirect the user to the Azure AD authorization endpoint to obtain an authorization code. This can be done by launching a browser intent to the URL https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?client_id={client_id}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}, where {tenant} is the tenant ID, {client_id} is the client ID obtained in step 1, and {redirect_uri} is a registered redirect URI in your Azure AD app.

Comment: @Sourav it is possible to authorize yourself via a browser intent, but obtaining the authorization code requires fetching information from the page after login. The other problem is that the code is put in the redirect url instead of the web page. As far as I know you can't fetch the url after login using something like a web scraper. Do you know any way of fetching information from a browser intent like this?